# Install Oracle 12 or 19 Client with ODBC on Ubuntu 18?

Tags: linux, oracle, ubuntu, odbc

I am trying to get the Oracle 12c or Oracle 19 Instant Client and ODBC drivers installed on Ubuntu Server 18.   I've followed all the directions I can find, but ultimately get an error.  Here are the instructions I've followed.

Here are the instructions they furnished and have followed to the T:

```
1. Create the /opt/oracle directory:
sudo mkdir /opt/oracle

2. Go to https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html and 
download the following packages:
oracle-instantclient12.2-basic-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.zip
oracle-instantclient12.2-odbc-12.2.0.1.0-2.x86_64.zip

3. Unzip both files into /opt/oracle:
sudo unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip -d /opt/oracle
sudo unzip instantclient12.2-odbc-12.2.0.1.0-2.x86_64.zip -d /opt/oracle

4. Create a symlink to instantclient:
cd /opt/oracle
sudo ln -s instantclient_12_2 instantclient

5. Add the driver to /etc/odbcinst.ini:
[OracleODBC]
Description=Oracle ODBC driver for Oracle
Driver=/opt/oracle/instantclient/libsqora.so.12.1
FileUsage=1

6. If /etc/odbc.ini does not exist, create it:
sudo touch /etc/odbc.ini

7. Add this content in odbc.ini:
[Oracle]
Driver = OracleODBC
ServerName = <servername>
Database = <database>
Server = <host>
Port = 1521
client_charset = 'UTF-8'

8. Update /opt/FM/FM\ Server/Data/TnsAdmin/tnsnames.ora to match odbc.ini:
<servername> =
(DESCRIPTION=
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<host>)(PORT=1521))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=<database>))
)
```

When I try to connect, I get an error.

"ODBC Error: [unixODBC] Driver Manager] Can't open lib '/opt/oracle/instantclient/libsqora.so.19.1': file not found.

I have a symlink setup in that directory and the file is installed there.   I have restarted and checked everything I know to check.  Any tips ideas would be appreciated.

If someone knows someone who can help, I'm willing to pay for some consulting time to get a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding to LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/oracle/instantclient`

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure your app has permissions to access the Instant Client directory.
- Use `ldconfig` to add the Instant Client libraries to the default library search path. This is shown in the Instant Client installation instructions https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html#ic_x64_inst

Comment: The documentation you reference is clear that only Oracle Linux, Red Hat Enterprise Linux, and SuSE Linux are supported.

Comment: There are plenty of Ubuntu users of Instant Client; they are aware of the lack of certification and Support.

Answer (score -1):

Oracle (client or server) is not supported on Ubuntu at all. It is designed for a completely different branch of Linux. Any suggestion otherwise is a hack that is not guaranteed to produce reliable results, if it works at all.

Comment: Well, the vendor is supporting the configuration.  But we are still in testing.  Other people have been able to get it to work.   This is not production, so at this point, I would be happy to get a hack that potentially works.   I'm new to Linux, but I thought that Ubuntu was a well supported server choice.

Comment: Oracle won't support it. If you ever had a problem, they would require you to switch operating systems before you could get help. Also, they won't certify that their software will be stable or provide expected output, be secure, etc. This configuration should not *ever* be used in a production environment.

Comment: Not all Linux distributions are created equal, and not all Linux software is supported on every distribution. There are significant differences between the Ubuntu and Red Hat kernels, and Oracle for whatever reason has chosen not to support Ubuntu.